# while placing order getting slow in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

Iam using custom plugin in magneto1.9.2.4,while placing the order it takes nearly 2minutes time to place the order.when i disabled the plugin it getting speed to place the order.

In that plugin observer.php file

```
        public function salesOrderPlace(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
try{
        Mage::log("New Order Placed");


        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order->getIncrementId());

        /*$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');       
        $incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId(); 
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);*/

        //$older_id = $order->getOriginalIncrementId();


        if ($order instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order)
        { 
          if($this->getHelper()->issalesOrderPlace())
          { 
            $mobilenumbers = $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone(); 
            $message = $this->getHelper()->getOrderMessage($order); //enter Your Message
            $customerName = $order->getCustomerName();
            //curlApicall : this method will return tru or fale.
            $retunValue = $this->getHelper()->curlApiCall($message,$mobilenumbers,$customerName,"New Order");   


          }
          if($this->getHelper()->issalesOrderPlaceForAdmin())
          { 
            $mobilenumbers = $this->getHelper()->getAdminMobileNumber();         
            $message = $this->getHelper()->getOrderMessageForAdmin($order); //enter Your Message
            $customerName = $order->getCustomerName();
            //curlApicall : this method will return tru or fale.
            $retunValue = $this->getHelper()->curlApiCall($message,$mobilenumbers,$customerName,"New Order");   


          } 
        }

    //return false;
  }catch(Exception $e) {
         Mage::log($e->getMessage());
  } 
}
```

I hope this is the file creating the issue.Can anyone figure out this

Helper code data.php

```
        <?php

       class Sms_Sms_Helper_Data extends Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Data
     {
       public function isEnable()
       {
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('sms/general/enable',$storeId);
       }
    public function isMobileVerifcatoinRequired()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('sms/general/verifyrequired',$storeId);
}
public function getLanguage()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    Mage::log(Mage::getStoreConfig('sms/general/smslanguage',$storeId));
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('sms/general/smslanguage',$storeId);
}
public function generateRandomString()
{
    $length = 8;
    $randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);

    return $randomString;
}
public function isAdminReportEnable()
{
    Mage::log("IN Configuration ");
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    Mage::log(Mage::getStoreConfig('sms/registeredcustomer/enable',$storeId));
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('sms/registeredcustomer/enable',$storeId);
}
public function getAdminReportTime()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('sms/registeredcustomer/smssendreporttoadmin',$storeId);
}
public function getLastCalledCronTime()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('sms/sendtimelyreport/time',$storeId);
}
public function getOtpStringlenght()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('sms/general/otp',$storeId);
}

public function getUsername()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('sms/general/username',$storeId);
}

public function getPassword()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    return Mage::helper('core')->decrypt(Mage::getStoreConfig('sms/general/password',$storeId));
}

public function getApiUrl()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('sms/general/apiurl',$storeId);
}
public function getSmsCharcterCount()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    if($this->isEnable())
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('sms/general/smstextchar',$storeId);
    }
    return false;
}
public function getSenderId()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('sms/general/sms',$storeId);
}

public function iscontactFormForAdmin()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    if($this->isEnable())
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('admintemplate/contactus/enable',$storeId);
    }
    return false;
}

public function isCustomerRegisterSuccess()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    if($this->isEnable())
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('usertemplate/customer/enable',$storeId);
    }
    return false;
}
public function isCustomerRegisterSuccessForAdmin()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    if($this->isEnable())
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('admintemplate/customer/enable',$storeId);
    }
    return false;
}

public function issalesOrderPlace()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    if($this->isEnable())
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('usertemplate/orderplace/enable',$storeId);
    }
    return false;
}
public function issalesOrderPlaceForAdmin()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    if($this->isEnable())
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('admintemplate/orderplace/enable',$storeId);
    }
    return false;
}
public function isInvoceRegister()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    if($this->isEnable())
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('usertemplate/invoicegerate/enable',$storeId);
    }
    return false;
}
public function isCancelOrder()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    if($this->isEnable())
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('usertemplate/cancelorder/enable',$storeId);
    }
    return false;
}
public function isCompleteOrder()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    if($this->isEnable())
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('usertemplate/completeorder/enable',$storeId);
    }
    return false;
}
public function isReturnOrder()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    if($this->isEnable())
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('usertemplate/returnorder/enable',$storeId);
    }
    return false;
}
public function isReturnOrderForAdmin()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    if($this->isEnable())
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('admintemplate/returnorder/enable',$storeId);
    }
    return false;
}
public function getAdminMobileNumber()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('sms/general/adminmobile',$storeId);
}
public function isupdateOrderTrackingNumber()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    if($this->isEnable())
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('usertemplate/ordertracking/enable',$storeId);
    }
    return false;
}
public function getContactFormMessageForAdmin($name,$email,$CustomerNumber,$comment)
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    $storeurl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
    $storename = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();

    $codes = array('{{name}}','{{email}}','{{mobilenumber}}','{{shop_name}}','{{shop_url}}','{{comment}}');
    $accurate = array($name,$email,$CustomerNumber,$storename,$storeurl,$comment);

    return str_replace($codes,$accurate,Mage::getStoreConfig('admintemplate/contactus/message',$storeId));
}
public function getCustomerMessage($name,$firstname,$lastname,$randomcode)
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    $storeurl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
    $storename = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();

    $codes = array('{{name}}','{{first_name}}','{{last_name}}','{{random_code}}','{{shop_name}}','{{shop_url}}');
    $accurate = array($name,$firstname,$lastname,$randomcode,$storename,$storeurl);
    return str_replace($codes,$accurate,Mage::getStoreConfig('usertemplate/customer/message',$storeId));
}
public function getCustomerMessageForAdmin($name,$firstname,$lastname,$randomcode)
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    $storeurl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
    $storename = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();

    $codes = array('{{name}}','{{first_name}}','{{last_name}}','{{random_code}}','{{shop_name}}','{{shop_url}}');
    $accurate = array($name,$firstname,$lastname,$randomcode,$storename,$storeurl);
    return str_replace($codes,$accurate,Mage::getStoreConfig('admintemplate/customer/message',$storeId));
}
public function getOrderMessage(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    $storeurl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
    $storename = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();

    $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
    Mage::log("getOrderMessage");
    Mage::log($order->getGrandTotal());
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    $codes = array('{{shop_name}}','{{shop_url}}','{{first_name}}','{{last_name}}','{{street}}','{{fax}}','{{postal}}','{{city}}','{{email}}','{{order_id}}','{{order_total}}');
    $accurate = array($storename,
                           $storeurl,
                           $billingAddress->getFirstname(),
                           $billingAddress->getLastname(),
                           $billingAddress->getStreetFull(),
                           $billingAddress->getFax(),
                           $billingAddress->getPostcode(),
                           $billingAddress->getCity(),
                           $billingAddress->getEmail(),
                           $order->getIncrementId(),
                           number_format((float)$order->getGrandTotal(), 2, '.', '')
                            );

    return str_replace($codes,$accurate,Mage::getStoreConfig('usertemplate/orderplace/message',$storeId));
}
public function getOrderMessageForAdmin(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    $storeurl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
    $storename = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();
    $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
    Mage::log($order->getGrandTotal());

    $codes = array('{{shop_name}}','{{shop_url}}','{{first_name}}','{{last_name}}','{{street}}','{{fax}}','{{postal}}','{{city}}','{{email}}','{{order_id}}','{{order_total}}');
    $accurate = array($storename,
                           $storeurl,
                           $billingAddress->getFirstname(),
                           $billingAddress->getLastname(),
                           $billingAddress->getStreetFull(),
                           $billingAddress->getFax(),
                           $billingAddress->getPostcode(),
                           $billingAddress->getCity(),
                           $billingAddress->getEmail(),
                           $order->getIncrementId(),
                           number_format((float)$order->getGrandTotal(), 2, '.', '')
                            );

    return str_replace($codes,$accurate,Mage::getStoreConfig('admintemplate/orderplace/message',$storeId));
}
public function getMessageForShipment(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)
{
    $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    $storeurl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
    $storename = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();

    $codes = array('{{shop_name}}','{{shop_url}}','{{first_name}}','{{middlename}}','{{last_name}}','{{fax}}','{{postal}}','{{city}}','{{email}}','{{order_id}}');
    $accurate = array($billingAddress->getFirstname(),
        $billingAddress->getMiddlename(),
        $billingAddress->getLastname(),
        $billingAddress->getFax(),
        $billingAddress->getPostcode(),
        $billingAddress->getCity(),
        $billingAddress->getEmail(),
        $order->getIncrementId()
    );
    return str_replace($codes,$accurate,Mage::getStoreConfig('usertemplate/ordertracking/message',$storeId));
}
public function insertRandomCode($custoemrId)
{
    // insert record
    $currunt_Date = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $randomnumber = $this->generateRandomString();
    $randmoinsert =  Mage::getModel('sms/smsregisterotp');

    $randmoinsert->setRandomCode($randomnumber);
    $randmoinsert->setCreatedTime($currunt_Date);
    $randmoinsert->setCustomerId($custoemrId);
    $randmoinsert->save();

    return $randomnumber;
}
public function mobileVerified($customerid,$random_code)
{
    $random = Mage::getModel('sms/smsregisterotp')->getCollection()
              ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerid);
    if(count($random) > 0 )
    {         
        $firstItem = $random->getFirstItem(); 
        // isVerify = 1 : all ready verified
        // isVerify = 0 : still not veified
        if($firstItem->getIsVerify() == 1){
            echo "true";            
        }
        else if ($firstItem->getIsVerify() == 0 && $firstItem->getRandomCode() == $random_code){
            $firstItem->setIsVerify(1);
            $firstItem->save();
            echo "true";            
        }
        else{
            echo "false";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "false";
    }
}
public function isUserVerified($customerid)
{
    $random = Mage::getModel('sms/smsregisterotp')->getCollection()
              ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerid);
    if(count($random) > 0 )
    {         
        $firstItem = $random->getFirstItem(); 
        if($firstItem->getIsVerify() == 1){
            return "true";          
        }
        else{
            return "false";
        }
    }
    else{
        return "false";
    }
}
public function getTestMessage($message)
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    $storeurl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
    $storename = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();
    $codes = array('{{shop_name}}','{{shop_url}}','{{name}}','{{first_name}}','{{middlename}}','{{last_name}}','{{fax}}','{{postal}}','{{city}}','{{email}}','{{order_id}}','{{country_name}}','{{order_total}}','{{product_count}}','{{old_order_status}}','{{new_order_status}}','{{order_created_date}}','{{randm_code}}','{{random_code}}');

    $accurate = array($storename,$storeurl,'Name','First Name','Middle Name','Last Name','Fax','12345','City Name','test@gmail.com','10000001','India','$21000','5','Pending','Processing','25/12/2016','Gtvse258','Gtvse258'
    );
    return str_replace($codes,$accurate,$message);
}
public function testSmsApi($tab,$section)
{
            $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
            $message = Mage::getStoreConfig($tab.'/'.$section.'/'.'message',$storeId); 
            $message = $this->getTestMessage($message);
            $mobilenumbers =Mage::getStoreConfig($tab.'/'.$section.'/'.'testmobile',$storeId); 
            $customerName = "Admin Test";
            //curlApicall : this method will return tru or fale.
            $retunValue = $this->curlApiCall($message,$mobilenumbers,$customerName,"Test SMS");
}
public function previewTestSmsApi($tab,$section)
{

            $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
            $message = Mage::getStoreConfig($tab.'/'.$section.'/'.'message',$storeId); 
            $message = $this->getTestMessage($message);
            return $message;
}
public function getOrderStatusChagneMessage(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order,$newStatus,$storeConfigName)
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    $storeurl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
    $storename = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();

    $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
    $neworder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order->getIncrementId());
    $countryname = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getCountryTranslation($billingAddress->getCountry());

    $codes = array('{{shop_name}}','{{shop_url}}','{{first_name}}','{{last_name}}','{{street}}','{{fax}}','{{postal}}','{{city}}','{{country_name}}','{{email}}','{{order_id}}','{{order_total}}','{{product_count}}','{{old_order_status}}','{{new_order_status}}','{{order_created_date}}');
    $accurate = array(     $storename,
                           $storeurl,
                           $billingAddress->getFirstname(),
                           $billingAddress->getLastname(),
                           $billingAddress->getStreetFull(),
                           $billingAddress->getFax(),
                           $billingAddress->getPostcode(),
                           $billingAddress->getCity(),
                           $countryname,
                           $billingAddress->getEmail(),
                           $order->getIncrementId(),
                           $order->getGrandTotal(),
                           $order->getTotalItemCount(),
                           $order->getStatus(),
                           $newStatus,
                           $order->getCreatedAt(),
                     );

    return str_replace($codes,$accurate,Mage::getStoreConfig('usertemplate/'.$storeConfigName.'/message',$storeId));
}
public function getOrderStatusChagneMessageForAdmin(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order,$newStatus,$storeConfigName)
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    $storeurl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
    $storename = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();

    $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
    $neworder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order->getIncrementId());
    $countryname = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getCountryTranslation($billingAddress->getCountry());

    $codes = array('{{shop_name}}','{{shop_url}}','{{first_name}}','{{last_name}}','{{street}}','{{fax}}','{{postal}}','{{city}}','{{country_name}}','{{email}}','{{order_id}}','{{order_total}}','{{product_count}}','{{old_order_status}}','{{new_order_status}}','{{order_created_date}}');
    $accurate = array(     $storename,
                           $storeurl,
                           $billingAddress->getFirstname(),
                           $billingAddress->getLastname(),
                           $billingAddress->getStreetFull(),
                           $billingAddress->getFax(),
                           $billingAddress->getPostcode(),
                           $billingAddress->getCity(),
                           $countryname,
                           $billingAddress->getEmail(),
                           $order->getIncrementId(),
                           $order->getGrandTotal(),
                           $order->getTotalItemCount(),
                           $order->getStatus(),
                           $newStatus,
                           $order->getCreatedAt(),
                     );

    return str_replace($codes,$accurate,Mage::getStoreConfig('admintemplate/'.$storeConfigName.'/message',$storeId));
}
public function canResendOTP()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('sms/resendsms/enable',$storeId);
}
public function resendOTPCode($mobilenumber,$customerId)
{

    $message = $this->getResendOTPMessage($customerId,'resendsms');
    $mobilenumbers =$mobilenumber;
    $customerData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
    $customerName = $customerData->getFirstname() ." " .$customerData->getLastname();
    //curlApicall : this method will return tru or fale.
    $retunValue = $this->curlApiCall($message,$mobilenumbers,$customerName,"Resend OTP");       
}

public function getResendOTPMessage($customerId,$storeConfigName)
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    $storeurl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
    $storename = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();
    $custoemr = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerId);
    $randomcode = $this->chagneRandomCode($customerId); // will return new random code
    $codes = array('{{shop_name}}','{{shop_url}}','{{first_name}}','{{last_name}}','{{randm_code}}');
    $accurate = array(     $storename,
                           $storeurl,
                           $custoemr->getFirstname(),
                           $custoemr->getLastname(),
                           $randomcode,
                     );

    return str_replace($codes,$accurate,Mage::getStoreConfig('sms/'.$storeConfigName.'/message',$storeId));
}
public function chagneRandomCode($custoemrId)
{
    // insert record
    $currunt_Date = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $randomnumber = $this->generateRandomString();

    $random = Mage::getModel('sms/smsregisterotp')->getCollection()
              ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $custoemrId);
    if(count($random) > 0 )
    {         
        $firstItem = $random->getFirstItem(); 
        $firstItem->setRandomCode($randomnumber);
        $firstItem->setCreatedTime($currunt_Date);
        $firstItem->save();
    }
    return $randomnumber;
}
public function insertSmsReport($jobid,$message,$mobilenumbers,$customerName,$messageType)
{
 try{
    $messagecount = strlen($message);
    $messagecount = ceil($messagecount/$this->getSmsCharcterCount()); 
    $currunt_Date = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $smsreport =  Mage::getModel('sms/smsreport');

    $smsreport->setJobno($jobid);
    $smsreport->setMessageSentTime($currunt_Date);
    $smsreport->setMessageText($message);
    $smsreport->setRecipientName($customerName);        
    $smsreport->setRecipientNumber($mobilenumbers);
    $smsreport->setMessageType($messageType);
    $smsreport->setMessageStatus(0);
    $smsreport->setMessageCount($messagecount);

    $smsreport->save();
     }catch(Exception $e) {
         Mage::log($e->getMessage());
     }  
}
public function sendReportToAdmin()
{
 try{
    if($this->isAdminReportEnable())
    {
        $to = date("Y-m-d");
        $from = $this->getLastCalledCronTime();
        $diff = abs(strtotime($from) - strtotime($to)); 
        $days = floor($diff / (60*60*24));
        Mage::log("From " . $from);
        Mage::log("to " . $to);         
        Mage::log("Days " . $days . "needToCallTime ".$needToCallTime);
        $needToCallTime = $this->getAdminReportTime();
        if($needToCallTime == $days) // it will call when days = 1,7,30
        {
                $this->getCustomerRecoreWithinTimeDuration($from,$to,$days);
        }
        else
        {
                Mage::log('Today ('. date("Y-m-d h:i:s").') Adin will not get Message');
        }

        Mage::app()->cleanCache(); // will flush the cache. it Required beucase core_config_data called new data : getLastCalledCronTime() this method require flush the data
    }
    else
    {
        Mage::log("In else part ");
    }
 }catch(Exception $e) {
    Mage::log("Call Execption Gerate Cron Of sendReportToAdmin ");
 }
}
public function getCustomerRecoreWithinTimeDuration($from,$to,$messageInDays)
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to));
    Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('sms/sendtimelyreport/time', $to);

    $message = $this->getCustoemrCountMessage(count($collection),$messageInDays);
    $mobilenumbers = $this->getAdminMobileNumber();
    $customerName = "Admin";
    $retunValue = $this->curlApiCall($message,$mobilenumbers,$customerName,"Customer Registerd");
}
public function getCustoemrCountMessage($count,$messageInDays)
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    $storeurl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
    $storename = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();
    $codes = array('{{shop_name}}','{{shop_url}}','{{customer_count}}','{{day_month_week}}');
    $accurate = array($storename,$storename,$count,$messageInDays);

return str_replace($codes,$accurate,Mage::getStoreConfig('sms/registeredcustomer/message',$storeId));
}
public function curlApiCall($message,$mobilenumbers,$customerName,$messageType)
{
    if($this->isEnable())
    {
            Mage::log("Cal CurlApiCall Success");
            $custMessage = $message;
            $language = $this->getLanguage();
            Mage::log("language".$language);
            $message = urlencode($message); 
            $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();

            $senderid = $this->getSenderId(); //Your senderid
   //               $messagetype = "N"; //Type Of Your Message
               $messagetype = $language; //Type Of Your Message
              $DReports = "Y"; //Delivery Reports
            $url = $this->getApiUrl();
            $user = $this->getUsername();
            $password = $this->getPassword();


            $ch = curl_init();
            if (!$ch){die("Couldn't initialize a cURL handle");}
            $ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"User=$user&passwd=$password&mobilenumber=$mobilenumbers&message=$message&sid=$senderid&mtype=$messagetype&DR=$DReports");

            Mage::log("User=$user&passwd=$password&mobilenumber=$mobilenumbers&message=$message&sid=$senderid&mtype=$messagetype&DR=$DReports");

            $ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

            $curlresponse = curl_exec($ch); // execute
            Mage::log($curlresponse);
            $splitstring = explode(":", $curlresponse);
            $jobid = $splitstring[1];
            //insert recored in SMS Report
            $this->insertSmsReport($jobid,$custMessage,$mobilenumbers,$customerName,$messageType);

            if(curl_errno($ch))
                Mage::log(curl_error($ch));

            if (empty($ret)) 
            {
                die(curl_error($ch));
                curl_close($ch); // close cURL handler
                Mage::log("Cal CurlApiCall : error " );
                return "error";
            }
            else
            {
                $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
                curl_close($ch); // close cURL handler
                //echo "";
                //echo $curlresponse; //echo "Message Sent Succesfully" ;
            }
    return "true";      
    }
    else
    {
        return "false";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Whats is the `curlApiCall` ?

Comment: otp plugin related @KeyurShah

Comment: Please post your helper code

Comment: I update code with helper plz check once @KeyurShah

Comment: $retunValue = $this->getHelper()->curlApiCall($message,$mobilenumbers,$customerName,"New Order");   when it it was commented it is working,what is the problem in this

Comment: because it calls the API, that's why

Comment: so how to fix it @KeyurShah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you could look into this answer you might use `gzip` for curl to make it fast.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33875404/4098888

But still curl response totally depend on server response time.